# chromecast, integrate a sender app to a receiver app

Tags: chromecast, receiver

I am having trouble with google cast receiver app CastHelloVideoPlayer, which can be found from github/googlecast.

I followed the Setup Instructions specified on the github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideoPlayer webpage,
......

2. Uploaded the receiver.html of CastHelloVideoPlayer to my github account,
   https://github.com/PhilSSOO/myCastHelloVideoPlayer
3. Registered an application on the Developers Console. I got an app ID 3BFFF41A. I chose NOT to publish my app.
4. Registered the serial # of my chromecast device in the developer console.
5. I tried but failed to send my chromecast serial number to Google. My setup process didn't bring me to "send your serial number " step.
6. Rebooted chromecast ...... But I didn't see any indication that my chromecast picked up any changes.
7. Entered the app ID 3BFFF41A into my sender application, which is app_done of Cast iOS codelab tutorial,
   https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios/#0

(The app_done works fine --- able to cast videos to my TV via a chromecast device --- so I assume this sender app is communicating well with my chromecast)

(continuing the above 7) To be exact, I added 3BFFF41A to appDelegate.m file
......
GCKCastOptions *options =
      [[GCKCastOptions alloc] initWithReceiverApplicationID:3BFFF41A];
......

But I got an error,

invalid digit 'B' in decimal constant

I doubt this is not the way to integrate a sender app to a receiver app. My search on the internet didn't get me through.

Please Help.

Phil

Comment: Dear Mr. Nicholls,                     
initWithReceiverApplicationID:@"3BFFF41A" DID work.                        
Many thanks!                                                                                              Phil

Answer (score 0):

initWithReceiverApplicationID expects the app ID to be a string.

Comment: Dear Mr. Nicholls,                     
initWithReceiverApplicationID:@"3BFFF41A" DID work.                        
Many thanks!                                                                                              Phil